# The address of the specified listener name is incorrect while adding a listener

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

listener.ora

```
CALLOUT_LISTENER =
 (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS= (PROTOCOL= IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC))
 )

 log_directory_callout_listener = /FIN10_2_17/finadm/assure
 trc_directory_callout_listener = /FIN10_2_17/finadm/assure

 SID_LIST_CALLOUT_LISTENER =
   (SID_LIST =
     (SID_DESC =
       (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
       (ORACLE_HOME= /ORACLE/ora11203/app/db)
       (PROGRAM = /ORACLE/ora11203/app/db/bin/extproc)
     )
   )
```

tnsnames.ora

```
extproc_connection_data =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS =
      (PROTOCOL = IPC)
      (KEY = EXTPROC)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
    )
  )
```

I am trying to add a new listener in listener.ora file, I have named it as CALLOUT_LISTENER.
I am getting an error `specified listener name is incorrect` when I try to execute `lsnrctl start CALLOUT_LISTENER`